# Intersection and difference of two sets

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Given two sets `a` and `b` that both contain integers, I would like to create another set `c` that contains all integers that are in `a` **and** `b` and additionally each integer that is in `a` **xor** `b` with probability 1/2, e.g:

```
a={1,2,3,4}, b={1,2,5}
The result of function(a,b) could be c={1,2,5} or c={1,2,3,4,5} or c={1,2,3,5} or c={1,2,3,4} ....
```

This is a bottleneck in my code and is done iteratively many times. Currently my code is:

```
def function(a, b):
    c = a & b
    c_temp = list(a ^ b)

    for x in range(len(c_temp)):
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            c.add(c_temp[x])
    return c
```

Could this be done faster? Thanks!

Comment: How large are these sets?

Comment: The size can vary very much. They can be as small as  of size 1 but also 100 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is unnecessary, and range-len iteration is slower than direct iteration. You can iterate over `a ^ b` directly:

```
def function(a, b):
    c = a & b

    for x in a ^ b:
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            c.add(x)
    return c
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a speed up.

Comment: What does `a ^ b` and `a & b` do?

Comment: @AnnZen: For sets, `^` is symmetric difference and `&` is intersection. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 2):

I believe so!

Try the code below, which takes the loop out and let's the random module select from the xor set, which will be faster.  I used the binomial distribution to determine how many should be selected, which is the correct way to do this with each element being considered with p=0.5

```
#random selection

import numpy as np
import random


def f2(a, b):
    c = a & b
    xor_stuff = a^b
    xor_selected = random.sample(xor_stuff, np.random.binomial(len(xor_stuff), p=0.5))
    c.update(xor_selected)
    return c

a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
b =          {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

for trial in range(5):
    print(f2(a,b))
```

#### Yields:

```
{3, 4, 5, 6}
{1, 4, 5, 6, 7}
{2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9}
{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

### ---- Some speed testing of solutions. ----

### 4 variants:

```
# original
def f1(a, b):
    c = a & b
    c_temp = list(a ^ b)

    for x in range(len(c_temp)):
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            c.add(c_temp[x])
    return c


def f2(a, b):
    c = a & b
    xor_stuff = a^b
    xor_selected = random.sample(xor_stuff, np.random.binomial(len(xor_stuff), p=0.5))
    c.update(xor_selected)
    return c

def f3(a, b):
    c = a & b
    st = list(a ^ b)
    c.update(np.array(st)[np.random.random(len(st)) > 0.5])
    return c

def f4(a, b):
    c = a & b

    for x in a ^ b:
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            c.add(x)
    return c

test_size = 1000
a2 = {random.randint(0, 10_000_000) for t in range(test_size)}
b2 = {random.randint(0, 10_000_000) for t in range(test_size)}
```

#### Results...

(Sadly, mine is slowest!  surprised...  :( )

```
In [25]: %timeit f1(a2, b2)                                                     
391 µs ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit f2(a2, b2)                                                     
644 µs ± 2.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [27]: %timeit f3(a2, b2)                                                     
365 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [28]: %timeit f4(a2, b2)                                                     
342 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But the performance seems to be not improved unfortunately. The code I posted is actually twice as fast.

Comment: For large sets it takes the same amount of time, but for smaller sets my code is faster. Maybe I should just be happy with it?

Comment: let me do a couple speed tests... you say a typical instance is with set size of 100 ish?

Comment: Also, you say this is done iteratively...are the sets changing? or could you pre-compute this and store the answer(s)?  i.e.  there may be other optimizations...

Comment: It varies between 1 and 100..1000. Both sets change after iterations. I would have to think about that.

Comment: @HighwayJohn: Are the changes incremental? If so, maintaining the intersection and symmetric difference incrementally is likely to speed things up.

Comment: The changes are mostly small. I have to think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think making a uniform continuous random variable for a binary choice is a bit wasteful. So here is a suggestion using `random.getrandbits`:

```
import random
import itertools

def pp(a,b):
    out = a&b
    ab = a^b
    if ab:
        bitfield = map("1".__eq__,reversed(bin(random.getrandbits(len(ab)))))
        out.update(itertools.compress(ab,bitfield))
    return out
```

Alternatively, and perhaps clearer:

```
        bitfield = map("1".__eq__,f"{random.getrandbits(len(ab)):0{len(ab)}b}")
```

...

Comment: This code has a lot of subtleties that I *think* are handled correctly, particularly the handling of the `0b` in the `bin` output, the handling when the `bin` output is shorter than `ab` (because `bin` doesn't know what width to treat its input as), and the handling of the `len(ab) == 0` case. Even if it works, though, it takes a lot of thought from the reader to be sure that it works.

Comment: Timing indicates that this is pretty fast, although I expect that has more to do with avoiding interpreter overhead than it does with using less random bitstream output.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Nope, `getrandbits` chokes on input `0`, so the `a = b` case was not handled correctly. Thanks for bringing it up. I've also added an alternative which I think avoids some of the subtleties you highlighted.